# Excel calculating

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate like this

```
qty4*1Euro & qty3*1.5Euro = TOTAL
4*1 & 3*1.5 = TOTAL
```

I wrote in two ways with words and numbers and with numbers so you can understand what I want

[image: Image screenshot]

WHAT I TRIED

```
=A2:A100*$A$1
```

Comment: Seems pretty easy to translate to a formula. What did you try?

Comment: I try some other ways but they are long can you tell me the way that i asked for ?

Comment: No, this is relatively simple, so I think you should first show what you've tried and why it's not working. That's the way this forum works.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with what you've tried, thanks!

Comment: here what i tried https://prnt.sc/q6rjan like this it works but i want the way that i asked why should i say what way's i tried im not getting you ! im asking for help if you help ok if not i keep searching

Comment: No screenshot, just [edit] your question with the formula you tried.

Comment: And would you help me now ?

Comment: Yes I would :-)

Comment: `=SUM(C2:D2)` looks like it should be what you want.

Comment: `=SUM(A2*$A$1,B2*$B$1)` then copy/drag the formula down.

Comment: thank you it was too easy lol